# 'Command not found' when trying to install expo globally ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, expo, yarnpkg

When I install expo it installs but it doesn't install. Here are the details about the issue.

I start off by typing:

```
yarn global add expo-cli@4
```

When it installs it says:

```
warning package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "expo-cli > xdl > @expo/dev-server > @expo/metro-config > metro-react-native-babel-transformer@0.59.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@*".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
```

When I install expo using yarn I get:

```
Installed "expo-cli@4.12.0" with binaries:
      - expo
      - expo-cli
Done in 4.30s.
```

But when I type `'expo --version'` I get:

```
Command 'expo' not found, did you mean:

      command 'exo' from snap exoscale-cli (v1.22.2)
      command 'expn' from deb sendmail-base (8.15.2-18)
      command 'expr' from deb coreutils (8.30-3ubuntu2)
    
    See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

Comment: Did you try to restart the terminal?

Comment: Yes, i did try restarting the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you posted I'm assuming that the folder where yarn installs global node modules isn't in your path.

Try one of these:

1. Try installing globally with npm (which is probably in your path)

`npm i -g expo-cli`

2. Add yarn global folder to path:

`echo PATH="$PATH:$(yarn global bin)" >> ~/.bash_profile`

See this thread for more info: [Yarn global command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317578/yarn-global-command-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

1: Go to the terminal and first input this

export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin

2: After this command and enter this one

source ~/.bash_profile