# yarn global command failing on mac

Tags: yarnpkg

I am trying to add vtex using yarn but getting below error,

`Usage Error: The 'yarn global' commands have been removed in 2.x - consider using 'yarn dlx' or a third-party plugin instead`

[image]

```
yarn version: 3.2.0
Node: 16.14.0
NPM: 8.5.2
OS Details: MacOS Monterey, chip: apple m1 pro
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

### quick answer

Did you try to use `yarn dlx` instead of `yarn global` (removing the word `add`)? The resulting command:

```
yarn dlx vtex
```

### explanation & official doc reference

The above command is what the instruction in the error message means to recommend. Granted, "consider using 'yarn dlx' or a third-party plugin instead", could be clearer. Nonetheless it has some useful info.

The [yarn dlx documentation](https://next.yarnpkg.com/cli/dlx) is probably more to the point. Their example:

```
yarn dlx create-react-app ./my-app
```

The documentation explains that the `dlx` command uses a temporary environment in place of using global packages.

Most package manager maintainers have come to the conclusion that global package versions are problematic. You can find various discussions of why package manager maintainers are giving (and encouraging) alternatives, usually citing the issues developers encounter with different projects requiring different versions.

In any case, it's hard to argue that the best option is downgrading. Likely you'll not regret trying the up-to-date approach.

Answer (score -1):

On mac OS check yarn version by running command in terminal,

> yarn --version

If it is greater than or equal to 2. Please downgrade yarn version to 1.xx.x using,

> yarn set version 1.22.1