# graph-cli installs but is not getting read on MacOS

Tags: bash, blockchain, subgraph, thegraph

I am installing `@graphprotocol/graph-cli` with `yarn` with the command

```
yarn global add @graphprotocol/graph-cli
```

I get the success message saying:

```
success Installed "@graphprotocol/graph-cli@0.31.0" with binaries:
  - graph
```

But when I try to check its version with `graph init` it says:

```
zsh: command not found: graph
```

Comment: Is the `graph` binary in your PATH?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [yarn global command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317578/yarn-global-command-not-working)